# Relation doesn't exists while calling postgres function with parameters

Tags: postgresql

I have a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(
    g geometry, _tbl regclass, _tile regclass)
  RETURNS SETOF geometry AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    return query EXECUTE format('select geom from %s where tile_id = %s::varchar', _tbl, _tile);
         RETURN;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

which works if call the function like this

```
select test_function(st_geometryfromtext('POLYGON((-119.896896986135 39.2639920102033,-119.896896986135 39.2641790174996,-119.896710996922 39.2643649879886,-119.896710996922 39.2645519952849,-119.896896986135 39.2639920102033))'),
'public.test', '123')
```

but gives error when I call function with different _tile parameter

```
select test_function(st_geometryfromtext('POLYGON((-119.896896986135 39.2639920102033,-119.896896986135 39.2641790174996,-119.896710996922 39.2643649879886,-119.896710996922 39.2645519952849,-119.896896986135 39.2639920102033))'),
'public.ec_1_eur_1', '123_123_123')
```

gives error `ERROR:  relation "123_123_123" does not exist`

why does it not throw error for `'123'` but `'123_123_123'`. How should I solve this?

When adding varchar for _tile instead of regclass, it doesn't handle quotes within quotes

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_function(
    g geometry,
    _tbl regclass,
    tile varchar)
  RETURNS SETOF geometry AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    return query EXECUTE format('select geom from %s where tile_id = %s::varchar', _tbl, tile);
         RETURN;
END
$BODY$  
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I get an issue

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "_123_123"
LINE 1: select geom from test where tile_id = 123_123_123::var...
```

Comment: test_function() and select_gap_function() might be different, at least the name is different.

Comment: Why is _tile declared as regclass? You're using it to compare against tile_id (which, I guess, is a varchar column). Try declaring _tile as varchar in the function definition, that will probably fix the issue.

Comment: sorry select_gap_function was added by mistake

Comment: I added varchar as well but didn't work there as well. I bumped into another issue there

Comment: What issue did you run into after declaring _tile as varchar?

Comment: Declaring a parameter that is not a table name as `regclass` does not make any sense. Postgres will try to convert that string to a valid table name because of the implicit cast to `regclass`. The `_title_ parameter should most definitely be `varchar` or `text`. I would even question the use of `regclass` for the `_tbl` parameter. The `format(...%I%..)` will take care of proper quoting, no need for a regclass parameter.

Comment: I updated the question with issue with varchar as well. Initially I used varchar but don't know how to solve problem of quotes within quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [%I and %L](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to quote correctly and avoid SQL injection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_function(
    g geometry,
    _tbl regclass,
    tile varchar)
  RETURNS SETOF geometry AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    return query EXECUTE format('select geom from %I where tile_id = %L::varchar', _tbl, tile);
         RETURN;
END
$BODY$  
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: looks like only %L is enough and ::varchar is not needed.